# How do I align tokens and their labels from one list with another list?

Tags: alignment, token

I have 2 lists that each contain a token and a label per instance. I want to keep one list as a base, and make the other list aligned to the base-list. I want to calculate the confusion matrix values, so the labels (for each token) needs to be aligned. Sometimes a token in a_list is a_list[i] = ':' (a_label[i] = 'B') and a_list[i+1] = 'DW' (a_label[i+1] = 'I'), and b_list[i]=':DW' (b_label[i] = '-').
How can I fix this issue?

I want my result to be a csv-format file where the first column consists of the tokens of a_list, the second column consists of the labels of a_list, and the third column consists of the labels of b_list, all aligned.